# HTML CSS code cleaning

Tags: html, css

I started my learnig process of HTML and CSS, and i wonder is there any chance i can check my code, not by walidating it on w3. I want to know what i could do better or what I am doing wrong etc.
From my sie i can say, that I'm watching tonse of tutorials, but always I have a tons of questions when I'm doing something on my own.
I know that can be time consuming for someone, that why I just wonder: maybe there is a page like w3 walidator, byt ponting my mistakes.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5SOiIsAziJl6AWe0HWRKTXlfcSHKmYV4RBF18PPJ173Kzn7jzMyFuTtk8JA7QQG1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="grid.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="strona_3.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <header><!-- pocztek nagłówka-->
        <div class="section kontener kontener-nav">
            <nav>
                <div class="naglowek-top">
                    <p class="naglowek-top-text">Litwo! Ojczyzno moja! Ty jesteś jak zdrowie.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <ul class="nav-glowna-lewa nav-glowna">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <p class="nav-srodek">
                            <span clas="text-logo">logologologo logologo</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                        <ul class="nav-glowna-prawa nav-glowna">
                            <li><a href="#">strona1</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#">blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">kontakt</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                 </div><!--koniec row-->
            </nav><!-- koniec nav -->
        </div><!-- koniec sektion oraz kontener -->
    </header><!-- koniec nagłówka-->
    <section class="hero1"><!-- sekcja hero-->
        <div class="kontener">
            <div class="hero1-text">
                <h1>Litwo! Ojczyzno moja! Ty jesteś jak zdrowie.</h1>
            </div>
        </div><!-- koniec sektion oraz kontener -->
    </section><!-- koniec hero-->
    <section class="about">
        <div class="kontener">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Twych świątyń progi iść za rarogiem zazdroszczono domowi, przed oczy wkoło pali.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span_1_of_2 vl">
                    <img src="img/person.jpg" alt="phota of a person" class="ld">
                </div>
                <div class="col span_1_of_2 o-mnie-div">
                    <h3>Tymczasem na to mówiąc, że tytuły przychodzą z rana</h3>
                    <p class="o-mnie-text para">Tadeuszem idą pod strażą. Dziś piękność twą w miechu. Starzy na tem, Że gościnna i dwie twarze w bliskiej wiosce
                        na miejsce jest armistycjum, to mówiąc, że przymiotów jego proszę Pana Mówiąc, Podkomorzemu ścisnął za domem
                        urządzał wieczerzę. on lubił gesta)</p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- koniec row-->
        </div><!-- koniec sektion oraz kontener -->
    </section><!-- koniec about-->
    <section class="technologia"><!-- technologia pocztek-->
        <div class="kontener">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Rumienił się, toczył zdumione źrenic gorzały przeciw czarów. Raz w klasztorze.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span_2_of_4">
                    <i class="fab fa-html5 ikony-duze"></i>
                    <p class="text-ikony para">Ciszę przerywał ale nigdzie nie jest obrazów wspaniałych zarysem</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col span_2_of_4">
                    <i class="fab fa-css3 ikony-duze "></i>
                    <p class="text-ikony para">Wyczha! poszli, a starzy mówili myśliwi widząc, że przeszkadza kulturze,</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span_2_of_4">
                    <i class="fab fa-js-square ikony-duze"></i>
                    <p class="text-ikony para">Żaden pan Rejent, na Ojczyzny łono. Tymczasem na nim się nie mogą</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col span_2_of_4">
                    <i class="fas fa-code ikony-duze"></i>
                    <p class="text-ikony para">Francuzów sto wozów sieci w ziemstwie, potem cały las drogi i znowu je w bitwie, gdzie usłyszał głos zabierać</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!-- technologia koniec-->
    <section class="hero2"><!--sekcja hero2-->
        <h4 class="hero2-text">Uciszcie się! woła. Marząc i pan Wojski z palcami ruch chartów tym obrazem.</h4>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-strona1">strona1</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-kontkat">kontakt</a>
    </section><!--sekcja hero 2 koniec-->

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

    /* ---- reusable ---- 
font color: color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
background color background-color: rgba(255, 203, 59, 0.925);

*/


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

html{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
}
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/*---- WSPÓLNE ---- */
.kontener{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.row {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.row:after {
    clear:both;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
h2,h3{
     letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
h1{
    margin:0;
    font-size: 200%;
    color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
h2{
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 45px;
    font-size: 160%;
}
h3{
    font-size: 120%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
h2::after{
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background-color: #000000;
    width:150px;
    height:2px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
/* .vl{
    height: 0 auto;
    border-right: 3px solid #00000067;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
} */

/* ---- ANIMACJE ---- */
@keyframes shake{
     0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
    30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
    70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
    80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
    90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
    from {background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.897);}
    to {background-color: rgb(129, 129, 129);}
    from{color: #fff;}
    to{color:rgb(88, 88, 88); }
}

/* ---- NAWIGACJA ---- */

.kontener-nav{
    max-height: 85px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 203, 59, 0.925);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.664);

}
.naglowek-top{
   text-align: right;
   padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.naglowek-top-text{
    font-size: 60%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;

}
.naglowek-top{
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.nav-glowna{
    font-size: 80%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-glowna-lewa{
    float: left;
}
.nav-glowna-prawa{
    float: right;
}
.nav-glowna-lewa li,
.nav-glowna-prawa li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    /* margin-top:15px; */
}
.nav-glowna-lewa li{
    /* padding-left: 10px; */
    margin-left: 80px;
}
.nav-glowna-prawa li{
    margin-right: 80px;
}
.nav-glowna-lewa li:first-child{
    padding-left: 150px;
}
/* .nav-glowna-lewa li:last-child{
    padding-left: 50px;
} */
.nav-glowna-prawa li:first-child{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.nav-glowna-prawa li:last-child{
    margin:0;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
.nav-glowna-lewa li a:link,
.nav-glowna-lewa li a:visited,
.nav-glowna-prawa li a:link,
.nav-glowna-prawa li a:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        color:rgb(88, 88, 88);
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
        transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}
.nav-glowna-lewa li a:hover,
.nav-glowna-prawa li a:hover{
    border-bottom:5px solid #fff;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}
.nav-srodek{
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    /* margin-top: 10px; */
    padding: 20px 85px;
    height: 0 auto;
    width:0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.897);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 55px;
}
.nav-srodek:hover{
    animation: shake 0.5s ease-in-out infinite; 
}
/* ---- HERO ---- */

.hero1,
.hero2{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.hero1-text,
.hero2-text{
    width: 1140px;
    top:50%;
    left:60%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
}
.hero1{
    background-image: url(img/hero_3.jpg);
    height: 650px;
}
.hero2{
    background-image: url(img/hero_1.jpg);
    height: 350px;
}
.hero1-text{
    position: absolute;
}
.hero2-text{
    position: relative;
}
.btn-strona1,
.btn-kontkat{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top:190px;
    margin-left: 280px;
}
.btn-kontkat:last-child{
    margin-left:10px;
}
.btn{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:rgb(88, 88, 88);
    background-color: rgba(253, 234, 62, 0.774);
    border-radius: 25%;
    padding:25px;
}

/* ---- about ---- */
.ld{
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.o-mnie-text{
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.o-mnie-div{
    margin-top: 55px;
}

/* ---- TECHNOLOGIA ----*/
.technologia{
    background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}
.text-ikony{
    height: 0 auto;
    width: 175px;
    padding-left: 245px;
    display: block; 
}
.ikony-duze{
    font-size: 450%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: I think your looking for [CSS Lint](http://csslint.net/)

Comment: [codereview.se]